# Django chartit 2 - multiple series in one simple Chart

Tags: python, django, charts

After successfull uses of Django Chartit 2 for building graphs (simple Line Chart and differents uses of Pivot Chart) I tried to make a Line Chart with data coming from different models. It failed and I tried to copy the example [provided here](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/demo/chart/multi-table-same-x/)

It failed too and am wondering why, my guess was that it may be related to Python 3 migration of Chartit 2 (I'm using Python 3.5 / Django 1.8 / Chartit 0.2.2) as the example if from the Chartit 1 documentation. Maybe it hasn't been adapted to Python 3, but I can't solve the issue... Here is my code :

- views : exactly as the example provided
- Traceback :

> TypeError at /space/reports/2
>
> unorderable types: dict() < dict()
>
> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/space/reports/2
>
> Django Version:    1.8.6
>
> Exception Type:    TypeError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> unorderable types: dict() < dict()
>
> Exception Location:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site->packages\chartit\charts.py in _groupby_x_axis_and_vqs, line 159

- Full Traceback :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
>                                  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
>
> C:\Users\Usuario1\space\reports\views.py in reports3
>                                      'text': 'Month number'}}}) ...
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\chartit\charts.py in **init**
>                      self.x_axis_vqs_groups = self._groupby_x_axis_and_vqs() ...
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\chartit\charts.py in _groupby_x_axis_and_vqs
>                          itr1 = sorted(itr1, key=sort_fn)

- The corresponding code in chartit\charts.py :

  ```
  dss = self.datasource.series
  x_axis_vqs_groups = defaultdict(dict)
  sort_fn = lambda td_tk: td_tk[1].get('xAxis', 0)
  so = sorted(self.series_options.items(), key=sort_fn)
  x_axis_groups = groupby(so, sort_fn)
  for (x_axis, itr1) in x_axis_groups:
      sort_fn = lambda td_tk: dss[td_tk[1]['_x_axis_term']]['_data']
                  **itr1 = sorted(itr1, key=sort_fn)**
      for _vqs_num, (_data, itr2) in enumerate(groupby(itr1, sort_fn)):
          x_axis_vqs_groups[x_axis][_vqs_num] = _x_vqs = {}
          for tk, td in itr2:
              _x_vqs.setdefault(td['_x_axis_term'], []).append(tk)
  return x_axis_vqs_groups
  ```

Thanks a lot if you can help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this post by Alexander Todorov may help:

> The problem is that the second elements in both lists have different
>   keys and Python doesn't know how to compare them. In earlier Python
>   versions this has been special cased as described here by Ned
>   Batchelder (the author of Python's coverage tool) but in Python 3
>   dictionaries have no natural sort order.  In the case of
>   django-chartit (of which I'm now the official maintainer) this bug
>   triggers when you want to plot data from multiple sources (models) on
>   the same chart. In this case the fields coming from each data series
>   are different and the above error is triggered.

Link to the bug description : http://atodorov.org/blog/2016/08/05/python-2-vs-python-3-list-sort-causes-bugs/

Comment: Yes it may well be that. I will look for future updates of django-chartit to see if it is corrected, thanks !